# texstudio syncronization misplacement

Tags: pdf, texstudio

My choice of tex Editor is texstudio.

When I want to sync between pdf and text, there are places that it shows the misplace location. Specifically, when I cntrl+click on a tex near an image it doesn't go to text but instead to the image. I have tried to use one column instead of double column and larger fontsize to mitigate this problem, but it didn't work out.

#### How can I get better synchronization?